# bison - pass values to next production

Tags: bison, abstract-syntax-tree

```
field_dec: type id_list        ;                                               

id_list: ID punct id_list                                             
         | ID SQUARE_OPEN INTEGER SQUARE_CLOSED punct id_list
         | ID punct
         | ID SQUARE_OPEN INTEGER SQUARE_CLOSED punct
 ;

type: INT | BOOLEAN
;

punct: COMMA | SEMICOLON
;
```

I have a bison grammar as given above and I am trying to create an AST for my programming language using this grammar. This grammar is to parse field declarations such as:

```
int a;

int a, b, c[10], d;

int a[10];
```

I wanted to ask how can I pass the value of "type" non-terminal to the bison parser when it reaches the production `id_list`.

I mean to say that when I am at `id_list` production in my parsing stage I want to have the type of every identifier as I need to store it in the identifier node. I know we can pass the `$$` value to the upper productions but how to pass some value to the productions which come after a production in the parsing stage.

After posting the question I found out that we can use `$n` with n < 0 but I can't find any good resource on the net to read about it and also I tried to test `$n` with n < 0 but it just gives me the following error:

```
bison.y:125.45-46: error: $0 of ‘callout_arg’ has no declared type         
             | STRING {printf("testing %s\n", $0);};       
                                              ^^
```

and

```
bison.y:124.43-45: error: $-1 of ‘callout_arg’ has no declared type
 callout_arg: expr {printf("testing %s\n", $-1);}
                                           ^^^
```

Comment: Your grammar doesn't look right. `id_list` has no terminating branch: Every `id_list` must be followed by another `id_list`, i.e. it's infinite.

Comment: @melpomene yeah thanks for  that i missed it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using right-recursion to define `id_list`, which is practically never what you want, you can achieve the desired effect with a left-recursive rule.

In the following grammar, the type associated with the declarator is always available as the semantic value of the declarator itself. I also corrected the handling of punctuation: only commas separate identifiers while only semi-colons terminate declarations.

To make the type always available, it is necessary to "denormalize" the grammar, which leads to a certain amount of repetition. See below for a slightly refactored version.

```
decl_list: type ID                  { assign_type($1, $2); }
         | type ID '[' INTEGER ']'  { assign_array_type($1, $2, $4); }
         | decl_list ',' ID         { assign_type($1, $3); }
         | decl_list ',' ID '[' INTEGER ']'
                                    { assign_array_type($1, $3, $5};

field_dec: decl_list ';'
```

For simplicity, I assumed that all semantic values are just strings, but in practice you would probably want specific types representing "type" and "identifier". Also, it would be a lot cleaner to avoid the excess repetition of all the possible declarator syntaxes, since there may well be more than two possibilities. This can also be achieved using a custom semantic type.

Here's a slightly more elaborate version:

```
%{
#include <stdbool.h>

enum Type {BOOLEAN, INTEGER};
struct Declarator {
    const char* id;
    bool        is_array;
    int         dimension;
}
%}

%union {
    enum Type         type;
    struct Declarator decl;
    const char*       id;
    long              number;
}

%{
   /* Pass semantic values by reference to avoid copying,
      since the struct Declarator is a bit big.
    */
   void assign_type_from_decl(const char** typ,
                              struct Declarator* dec) {
     if (dec->is_array)
       assign_array_type(*typ, dec->id, dec->dimension);
     else
       assign_type(*typ, dec->id);
   }
%}

%token <id>     T_ID
%token <number> T_INTEGER
%token          T_INT     "int"
                T_BOOLEAN "boolean"
%type <type> decl_list
%type <decl> declarator

%%

type     : "boolean"                { $$ = BOOLEAN; }
         | "int"                    { $$ = INTEGER; }
field_dec: decl_list ';'
decl_list: type declarator          { assign_type(&$1, &$2); }
         | decl_list ',' declarator { assign_type(&$1, &$3); }
declarator: ID                      { $$.id = $1;
                                      $$.is_array = false;
                                    }
         | ID '[' INTEGER ']'       { $$.id = $1;
                                      $$.is_array = true;
                                      $$.dimension = $3;
                                    }
```

It would be possible to replace the use of the Declarator structure by using a stack "up-reference", as indicated in the question. These references are, in my opinion, a bit fragile since they depend on global knowledge about the context in which a production can occur, and bison does not verify the use. One consequence of the lack of validation is that you *must* specify a semantic type tag when you use such a reference, a fact which is left implicit in the bison manual, which is why you are getting an error message from bison.

Ensuring that the stack is correctly configured for the semantic action is tricky, and usually requires the use of marker productions (or mid-rule actions). The following example is adapted from the bison manual, with the addition of the necessary explicit type syntax:

```
 %type <number> sum expr retainer
 %%

 sum:
   expr retainer '+' expr  { ... }
 | expr retainer '-' expr  { ... }
 ;

 retainer:
   /* empty */    { previous_expr = $<number>0; }
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to previous values on the values stack with `$<type>0` or `$<type>-N`, though you need to be careful to always get the type right. In your case, you likely want something like:

```
%type<type> type
    ... other type declarations for productions

%%

field_dec: type id_list ';' ;

id_list: id_decl { $$ = make_list($1); }
       | id_list ',' { $<type>$ = $<type>0; } id_decl { $$ = append_list($1, $3); }
       ;

id_decl: ID { $$ = declare_id($1, $<type>0; }
       | ID '[' INTEGER ']'
         { $$ = declare_id($1, get_array_type($<type>0, $3)); }
       ;

type: INT { $$ = &int_type; } | BOOLEAN { $$ = &bool_type; }

field_dec_list : /* empty */ | field_dec_list field_dec ;
```

If you use [btyacc](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/btyacc), it has syntactic sugar to make this easier (and more type safe):

```
%type<type>  type
%type<???>   id_decl(<type>)
%type<list>  id_list(<type>)    
    ... other type declarations for other productions

%%

field_dec: type id_list($1) ';' ;

id_list($t): id_decl($t) { $$ = make_list($1); }
           | id_list($t) ',' id_decl($t) { $$ = append_list($1, $3); }
       ;

id_decl($t): ID { $$ = declare_id($1, $t); }
           | ID '[' INTEGER ']' { $$ = declare_id($1, get_array_type($t, $3)); }
           ;

type: INT { $$ = &int_type; } | BOOLEAN { $$ = &bool_type; }

field_dec_list : /* empty */ | field_dec_list field_dec ;
```